# How to write text to a local file

Tags: io, abap, sap-bsp

I'm trying to write text to a local file (i.e. on my laptop) using the following code:

```
data: fname(60), text type string value 'la la la'.
fname = 'myfile.txt'.
OPEN DATASET fname FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE encoding default.
TRANSFER text TO fname.
CLOSE DATASET fname.
write 'done'.
```

The program runs fine and "done" appears after execution. However I cannot find the text file "myfile.txt" on my PC (it's not in the SAP work directory).

*Additional Info*

I have gotten this working using the function module `GUI_DOWNLOAD`, however I have to use the [OPEN DATASET](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapopen_dataset.htm) and [TRANSFER](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abaptransfer.htm) statements as I'm writing this in a background program (to be called by a [BSP](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_NETWEAVER_700/7.0.36/en-US?q=What%20is%20a%20BSP%20Application%3F) using [`SUBMIT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapsubmit.htm)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to write to a client while in background processing because nature of background processing is that no client machine has to be connected to the WAS. By default all files are save into sever directory `DIR_HOME`.

**SOLUTION:**
Generally downloading data is achieved by setting the right HTTP header fields and pushing the binary data into the http response with the help of `cl_bsp_utility=>download`.

This class sets the right content headers in your response. 
You have to specify your data in `XSTRING` form and specify which `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` you want, for example `application/vnd.ms-excel` or  `application/octetstream`.

Also `Content-Disposition` can be used to tell the browser the default filename to use, see

```
attachment; filename=filexyz.xls`
```

**P.S.**
For general information on working with files in ABAP you can refer to  this help file http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Working+with+files

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Creating the file on the server and offering a download option seems like the best idea. The program is if I write a program to save "afile.txt" to the server, I cant seem to find it on the server. Do you know the default location where files from programs are saved, or how to find the location?

Comment: Thank you very much for that information. I have been at this for hours and cannot figure out how to download the file from the server to my box. I have found the text file "myfile.txt" using AL11. So its path is "./myfile.txt". I have tried using FM's like 'ARCHIVFILE_SERVER_TO_SERVER' but this is only for copying on an AS. I have also tried range of the 'cl_gui_frontend_services' methods with no joy. Have you done this before and have sample code. I would have thought that downloading a file through a BSP was easier than this is turning out to be! Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @B.Bowles I have no real code example I can share at the moment but updated my answer with the basic idea.

Answer (score 5):

The OPEN DATASET and related keywords operate on files on the server only. There are various other options for getting the file on to the target machine from a background process.

1. If your server and client machines run on Windows, you can map a Windows path in AL11 and save the file there. (Note that you will have to open the target Windows machine firewall to allow this traffic).
2. You can run an FTP server on the target machine and ftp the files there. SAP has function modules to deal with this. Look at function group SFTP.
3. If both machines run some version of UNIX, you can even [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) the files on to the target machine (as most Unixes will include ssh and therefore scp). You will have to create an external command in SM49 and then set up public key authentication from the server to the target machine, which is a bit more tricky if you don't have admin rights on the SAP server, but there are ways around that too.

Answer (score 0):

As Turismo wrote: In Background processing, you can not write on a PC. 
Writing to a PC needs a connected SAPGui (=Client).

`OPEN DATASET` and `TRANSFER` writes the data to the server.